# How to import code to svn from Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, svn, ios7, xcode5

I have started using new Xcode 5. I have added one new repository from that. Now i want to import new code from my local directory to that remote repository. I know how to do that in Xcode 4. I am finding option for checkout. But i am not finding any option for import code in new Xcode. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get any answer yet ?

Comment: no i don't get any answer yet.

Comment: Maybe this post will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246871/importing-a-project-into-a-remote-svn-server-in-xcode-5

Answer (score -2):

Xcode support his own repository tool. You can use SVNX a free ware tool to download the code .