# importing a project into a remote SVN server in XCode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Previously in XCode 4, in the Organizer screen, in the Repositories section, there was an option (import) to import a project into an SVN server, this option is now disabled in Xcode 5's Source Control menu although the repository is added in the Accounts section in XCode's preferences.
how can I use this import feature with Xcode 5 to import my project into the remote SVN server ?

thanks in advance.

P.S. I don't want to import the project manually on the SVN Server, because I faced problems with the manual import, and I also don't want to solve this problem by paying $20 to purchase and install the OSX Server product which is supposed to solve this problem by running the OSX Service on the SVN server machine.

Comment: hi! any solution on this??

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking. Are you trying to take a project that is on your local disk and create a SVN repository for it?

Comment: no, an empty repository for my project is already created inside the SVN server, i need to take my project files and put them (import them) into that repository using XCode 5

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19410994/1017340

Comment: @Mojtaba, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Mojtaba the link you posted depicts the process of adding an existing repository to Xcode and then checking out that repository into a local folder, what I need is kinda the opposite of this process, I want to add (import) my existing project into an empty already created SVN repository right from Xcode 5, this is simply done by pressing on the Import button in Xcode 4 but can't find a clue how to do it with XCode 5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Follow the same process from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19410994/1017340

Summery:

Checkout empty trunk to a folder let say : /local/

copy all codes (Xcode project) to /local/

Open Xcode project from /local

Now you are able to commit everything.

PS. There is no import functionality (like what you want) in Xcode 5.

Comment: when I copy the Xcode project into the empty checked out trunk, and open the project with Xcode there is a ( ? ) mark beside each file and when I try to commit it fails.

Comment: this solution didn't work for me, what has worked is the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894195/xcode-5-export-project-to-svn-repository?rq=1   which uses svn import command from Terminal

Comment: That import command is equal to a copy/past to svn directly which you didn't wanted. In general Xcode is not good at managing SVN I would recommend you to get "cornerstone" (not free). It has nice and clean interface. don't worry about any conflicts between that and xcode.

Comment: Plus if you have developer account with apple you can get OSX server for free, login to member center and there is an appstore code to redeem.

Comment: i have iOS developer membership but can't find the OS X server on the iOS dev center ? can you elaborate how to get the redeem code from there ?

Comment: login, go to iOS Dev Center, scroll down, you will see a button with code in it.